# C#: are both using and try-finally-Dispose bad options with StreamReader?

Tags: file-io, c#-2.0, dispose, idisposable, using

think about this:

```
StreamReader reader = null;

try
{
    reader = new StreamReader(_fileName);
}
catch
{
    //show error that file not found
    reader.Dispose();
    return false;
}

try
{
    //code to read file
}
catch
{
   //show error badly formed file
}
finally
{
    reader.Dispose();
}
//return
```

the code above does not work when file can't be opened because it calls Dispose for null which results in exception.

i don't want to use using because i want to separate problems with opening the file and reading it. This could be achieved with million different catches but i don't want to go that way. Plus if using is same as try-finally would "hidden Dispose" throw an unwanted exception anyway? which would be the best way when all i need is to catch an exception opening it and an exception reading it?

Thanks & BR - Matti

Comment: what i do now is that i test in 1st catch if (reader == null) before calling Dispose...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is better to use the [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx):

```
using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(_fileName))
{
}
```

The compiler will create the correct dispose semantics for you.

And you can still use `try` with this, not worrying about disposing it yourself:

```
try
{
    using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(_fileName))
    {
         try
         {
            //code to read the file
         }
         catch
         {
            //show error badly formed file
         }
    }
}
catch
{
    // show error that file not found
}
```

Comment: how could i be so stupid. I use that same structure elsewhere with all the ADO.NET classes (DbConnection, DbDataReader etc.) sorry for wasting ur time.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct if you check `reader` for null before calling any methods on it, whereever that reader is located.

Using statement is not mandatory but is desirable.

Answer (score 2):

You should check whether the reader is null before you dispose it. Like so:

```
StreamReader reader = null;
try
{
    //code to read file
}
catch
{
   //show error badly formed file
}
finally
{
  if( null != reader )
  {
    reader.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: I use using normally all the time with all IDisposable. But in this case I want to separate error opening and reading file. your using example has only one catch. I would have to catch many exceptions and then conclude which was thrown from opening and which was thrown from reading

Comment: @matti It depends on how deep you're willing to nest your code. You can use try-catch blocks within a using block.

Answer (score 1):

The `StreamReader` can throw the following exceptions so you could just handle these accordingly:-

```
ArgumentException
ArgumentNullException
FileNotFoundException
DirectoryNotFoundException
NotSupportedException
ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```